# Lottie Hamburger Menu usage in a responsive page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, navigation

I have added a lottie hamburger menu for a responsive one page site for the mobile break point. I would like two things happen as follows:

When clicked on one of the links the menu disappears.

at the same time the lottie animation goes back to hamburger icon state when clicked on a link, (it staying in X state)
Here is the link
https://codepen.io/OralYildiz/pen/abwvazw

```js
/*--Lottie Animation and Mobile Menu Appear---*/
const pageHeader = document.querySelector(".header");
const toggleMenu = document.querySelector(".toggle-menu");
const player = document.querySelector("lottie-player");
const menuWrapper = document.querySelector(".nav__menu");
const menuOpenedClass = "menu-open";
const noTransitionClass = "no-transition";
let timer;

toggleMenu.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  pageHeader.classList.toggle(menuOpenedClass);
  if (pageHeader.classList.contains(menuOpenedClass)) {
    this.setAttribute("aria-label", "Close navigation");
    this.setAttribute("aria-expanded", "true");
    player.getLottie().playSegments([0, 45], true);
  } else {
    this.setAttribute("aria-label", "Open navigation");
    this.setAttribute("aria-expanded", "false");
    player.getLottie().playSegments([45, 0], true);
    //player.getLottie().playSegments([46, 90], true);
  }
});

window.addEventListener("resize", function () {
  menuWrapper.classList.add(noTransitionClass);
  clearTimeout(timer);
  timer = setTimeout(function () {
    menuWrapper.classList.remove(noTransitionClass);
  }, 500);
});

/*=============== CHANGE BACKGROUND HEADER ===============*/
function scrollHeader() {
  const header = document.getElementById("header");
  // When the scroll is greater than 50 viewport height, add the scroll-header class to the header tag
  if (this.scrollY >= 50) header.classList.add("scroll-header");
  else header.classList.remove("scroll-header");
}
window.addEventListener("scroll", scrollHeader);

/*=============== SHOW SCROLL UP ===============*/
function scrollUp() {
  const scrollUp = document.getElementById("scroll-up");
  // When the scroll is higher than 200 viewport height, add the show-scroll class to the a tag with the scroll-top class
  if (this.scrollY >= 200) scrollUp.classList.add("show-scroll");
  else scrollUp.classList.remove("show-scroll");
}
window.addEventListener("scroll", scrollUp);

/*=============== SCROLL SECTIONS ACTIVE LINK ===============*/
const sections = document.querySelectorAll("section[id]");

function scrollActive() {
  const scrollY = window.pageYOffset;

  sections.forEach((current) => {
    const sectionHeight = current.offsetHeight;
    const sectionTop = current.offsetTop - 50;
    sectionId = current.getAttribute("id");

    if (scrollY > sectionTop && scrollY <= sectionTop + sectionHeight) {
      document
        .querySelector(".nav__menu a[href*=" + sectionId + "]")
        .classList.add("active-link");
    } else {
      document
        .querySelector(".nav__menu a[href*=" + sectionId + "]")
        .classList.remove("active-link");
    }
  });
}
window.addEventListener("scroll", scrollActive);

/*=============== SCROLL REVEAL ANIMATION ===============*/
const sr = ScrollReveal({
  distance: "60px",
  duration: 2500,
  delay: 400
  // reset: true
});

sr.reveal(`.home__header, .section__title`, { delay: 600 });
sr.reveal(`.home__footer`, { delay: 700 });
sr.reveal(`.home__img`, { delay: 900, origin: "top" });

sr.reveal(
  `.sponsor__img, .products__card, .footer__logo, .footer__content, .footer__copy`,
  { origin: "top", interval: 100 }
);
sr.reveal(`.specs__data, .discount__animate`, {
  origin: "left",
  interval: 100
});
sr.reveal(`.specs__img, .discount__img`, { origin: "right" });
sr.reveal(`.case__img`, { origin: "top" });
sr.reveal(`.case__data`);
```

```css
/*=============== GOOGLE FONTS ===============*/
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500;600&display=swap");
/*=============== VARIABLES CSS ===============*/
:root {
  --header-height: 3rem;
  /*========== Colors ==========*/
  --hue-color: 206;
  --black-color: hsl(var(--hue-color), 4%, 4%);
  --black-color-alt: hsl(var(--hue-color), 4%, 8%);
  --title-color: hsl(var(--hue-color), 4%, 95%);
  --text-color: hsl(var(--hue-color), 4%, 75%);
  --text-color-light: hsl(var(--hue-color), 4%, 65%);
  --white-color: #FFF;
  --body-color: hsl(var(--hue-color), 4%, 6%);
  --container-color: hsl(var(--hue-color), 4%, 10%);
  --text-gradient: linear-gradient(hsl(var(--hue-color), 4%, 24%), hsl(var(--hue-color), 4%, 8%));
  --scroll-thumb-color: hsl(var(--hue-color), 4%, 16%);
  --scroll-thumb-color-alt: hsl(var(--hue-color), 4%, 20%);
  /*========== Font and typography ==========*/
  --body-font: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  --biggest-font-size: 5rem;
  --bigger-font-size: 3.5rem;
  --big-font-size: 2.5rem;
  --h2-font-size: 1.25rem;
  --h3-font-size: 1.125rem;
  --normal-font-size: .938rem;
  --small-font-size: .813rem;
  --smaller-font-size: .75rem;
  --text-line-height: 2rem;
  /*========== Font weight ==========*/
  --font-medium: 500;
  --font-semi-bold: 600;
  /*========== Margenes Bottom ==========*/
  --mb-0-5: .5rem;
  --mb-0-75: .75rem;
  --mb-1: 1rem;
  --mb-1-5: 1.5rem;
  --mb-2: 2rem;
  --mb-2-5: 2.5rem;
  /*========== z index ==========*/
  --z-tooltip: 10;
  --z-fixed: 100;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 968px) {
  :root {
    --biggest-font-size: 7.5rem;
    --bigger-font-size: 4.5rem;
    --big-font-size: 4rem;
    --h2-font-size: 1.5rem;
    --h3-font-size: 1.25rem;
    --normal-font-size: 1rem;
    --small-font-size: .875rem;
    --smaller-font-size: .813rem;
  }
}

/*=============== BASE ===============*/
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  margin: var(--header-height) 0 0 0;
  font-family: var(--body-font);
  font-size: var(--normal-font-size);
  background-color: var(--body-color);
  color: var(--text-color);
}

h1, h2, h3 {
  color: var(--title-color);
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

button,
input {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

/*=============== REUSABLE CSS CLASSES ===============*/
.section {
  padding: 4rem 0 2rem;
}

.section__title {
  font-size: var(--bigger-font-size);
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: var(--mb-2-5);
}

.section__title-gradient {
  background: var(--text-gradient);
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
}

/*=============== LAYOUT ===============*/
.main {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  max-width: 968px;
  margin-left: var(--mb-1-5);
  margin-right: var(--mb-1-5);
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
}

/*=============== HEADER ===============*/
.header {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: var(--z-fixed);
  background: transparent;
}

/*=============== NAV ===============*/
.nav {
  height: var(--header-height);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav__logo {
  display: flex;
  width: 1.5rem;
}

/*.header .nav__menu {
  transform: translateY(-200px);
  transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
}*/

.header.menu-open .nav__menu{
  transform: translateY(80px);
}
.header .toggle-menu {
    width: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .nav__menu {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: var(--body-color);
    transform: translateY(-200px);
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 4rem 0 3rem;
    transition: .4s;
  }
}

.nav__list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  row-gap: 1rem;
}

.nav__link {
  color: var(--white-color);
  font-size: var(--h2-font-size);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: var(--font-semi-bold);
  background: var(--text-gradient);
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  transition: .4s;
}

.nav__link:hover {
  background: var(--white-color);
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
}

/* show menu */
.nav__menu.active {
  top: 0;
}

/* Change background header */
.scroll-header {
  background-color: var(--body-color);
}

/* Active link */
.active-link {
  background: var(--white-color);
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
}

/*=============== HOME ===============*/
.home__img {
  width: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -16rem;
  right: 1.5rem;
}

.home__data {
  padding-top: 5rem;
}

.home__header {
  position: relative;
}

.home__title {
  position: absolute;
  top: -4rem;
  left: 1rem;
  line-height: 6rem;
  font-size: var(--biggest-font-size);
  background: var(--text-gradient);
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
}

.home__subtitle {
  font-size: var(--big-font-size);
  margin-bottom: var(--mb-2-5);
}

.home__title-description {
  font-size: var(--h3-font-size);
  font-weight: var(--font-medium);
  margin-bottom: var(--mb-1);
}

.home__description {
  margin-bottom: var(--mb-2-5);
  line-height: var(--text-line-height);
}

.home__price {
  font-size: var(--h3-font-size);
  font-weight: var(--font-semi-bold);
  margin-left: var(--mb-0-75);
}

/*=============== BUTTONS ===============*/
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: var(--black-color);
  color: var(--white-color);
  padding: 1rem 1.25rem;
  border-radius: .5rem;
  transition: .3s;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: var(--black-color-alt);
}

.button__icon {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.button--flex {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  column-gap: .75rem;
}

/*=============== SPONSOR ===============*/
.sponsor__img {
  width: 90px;
}

.sponsor__container {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(110px, 1fr));
  row-gap: 5rem;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}

/*=============== SPECS ===============*/
.specs__container {
  position: relative;
}

.specs__content {
  row-gap: 1.5rem;
}

.specs__data {
  display: grid;
  row-gap: .25rem;
}

.specs__icon {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  color: var(--white-color);
}

.specs__title {
  font-size: var(--normal-font-size);
  font-weight: var(--font-medium);
}

.specs__subtitle {
  font-size: var(--smaller-font-size);
}

.specs__data:nth-child(1), .specs__data:nth-child(4) {
  margin-left: 1.5rem;
}

.specs__img {
  width: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2rem;
  right: -4rem;
}

/*=============== CASE ===============*/
.case__container {
  position: relative;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

.case__data {
  padding: 5rem 0 3rem;
}

.case__img {
  width: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -7rem;
}

.case__description {
  margin-bottom: var(--mb-1-5);
  line-height: var(--text-line-height);
}

/*=============== DISCOUNT ===============*/
.discount__container {
  position: relative;
  background-color: var(--container-color);
  padding: 2rem 1.5rem;
  border-radius: .75rem;
}

.discount__title {
  font-size: var(--h3-font-size);
  margin-bottom: var(--mb-0-75);
}

.discount__description {
  margin-bottom: var(--mb-1);
}

.discount__img {
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4rem;
  right: -11rem;
}

/*=============== SCROLL UP ===============*/
.scrollup {
  position: fixed;
  right: 1rem;
  bottom: -20%;
  display: flex;
  background-color: var(--container-color);
  border-radius: .25rem;
  padding: .45rem;
  opacity: 9;
  z-index: var(--z-tooltip);
  transition: .4s;
}

.scrollup:hover {
  background-color: var(--black-color);
  opacity: 1;
}

.scrollup__icon {
  color: var(--white-color);
  font-size: 1.35rem;
}

/* Show Scroll Up*/
.show-scroll {
  bottom: 5rem;
}

/*=============== SCROLL BAR ===============*/
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: .60rem;
  border-radius: .5rem;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: var(--scroll-thumb-color);
  border-radius: .5rem;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background-color: var(--scroll-thumb-color-alt);
}

/*=============== MEDIA QUERIES ===============*/
/* For small devices */
@media screen and (max-width: 340px) {
  .container {
    margin-left: var(--mb-1);
    margin-right: var(--mb-1);
  }
  .section__title {
    font-size: var(--big-font-size);
  }
  .home__img {
    width: 200px;
    top: -13rem;
  }
  .home__title {
    top: -4rem;
    font-size: var(--bigger-font-size);
  }
  .home__data {
    padding-top: 1rem;
  }
  .home__description {
    font-size: var(--small-font-size);
  }
  .specs__img {
    width: 200px;
  }
  .case__container {
    grid-template-columns: .6fr 1fr;
  }
  .case__img {
    width: 220px;
    top: -2rem;
    left: -9rem;
  }
  .case__data {
    padding: 0;
  }
  .products__container {
    grid-template-columns: 142px;
    justify-content: center;
  }
}

/* For medium devices */
@media screen and (min-width: 576px) {
  .home__container {
    grid-template-columns: .8fr 1fr;
  }
  .home__data {
    padding-top: 2rem;
  }
  .home__img {
    top: -7rem;
    left: 0;
  }
  .specs__img {
    position: initial;
  }
  .specs__container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    justify-items: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .case__img {
    position: initial;
  }
  .case__data {
    padding: 0;
  }
  .case__container {
    grid-template-columns: max-content 250px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    column-gap: 2rem;
  }
  .discount__img {
    position: initial;
  }
  .discount__container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    justify-items: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .products__container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 142px);
    justify-content: center;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 767px) {
  body {
    margin: 0;
  }
  .section {
    padding: 6rem 0 2rem;
  }
  .nav {
    height: calc(var(--header-height) + 1.5rem);
  }
  .nav__logo {
    width: 2rem;
  }
  .nav__list {
    flex-direction: row;
    column-gap: 3.5rem;
  }
  .nav__link {
    font-size: var(--normal-font-size);
    text-transform: initial;
  }
  .toggle-menu {
    display: none;
  }
  .home__container {
    position: relative;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  }
  .home__img {
    top: -9rem;
    left: 4rem;
  }
  .home__data {
    padding-top: 8rem;
  }
  .specs__img {
    width: 300px;
  }
  .case__container {
    column-gap: 5rem;
  }
  .case__img {
    width: 300px;
  }
  .case__description {
    margin-bottom: var(--mb-2);
  }
  .discount__container {
    grid-template-columns: 250px max-content;
    justify-content: center;
    column-gap: 5rem;
    padding: 3rem 0;
  }
  .discount__title {
    font-size: var(--h2-font-size);
    margin-bottom: var(--mb-1);
  }
  .discount__description {
    margin-bottom: var(--mb-2);
  }
  .products__container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 162px);
    gap: 6rem 3rem;
    padding-top: 5rem;
  }
  .products__card {
    height: 152px;
    padding: .85rem;
  }
  .products__img {
    width: 95px;
  }
  .footer__container {
    grid-template-columns: .4fr .7fr .7fr 1fr;
  }
}

/* For large devices */
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .container {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
  .home__img {
    width: 300px;
    top: -15rem;
  }
  .home__title {
    top: -5rem;
    left: 3.5rem;
  }
  .home__description {
    padding-right: 5rem;
  }
  .sponsor__img {
    width: 100px;
  }
  .discount__img {
    width: 350px;
  }
  .footer__container {
    padding-top: 3rem;
  }
  .footer__copy {
    margin-top: 9rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="sr"><head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!--=============== FAVICON ===============-->
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://github.com/bedimcode/responsive-landing-page-headphones/blob/main/assets/img/favicon.png?raw=true" type="image/x-icon">

        <!--=============== REMIX ICONS ===============-->
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/remixicon@2.5.0/fonts/remixicon.css" rel="stylesheet">
<title>Responsive landing page headphones</title>

</head>

<body>
  <!--=============== HEADER ===============-->
<header class="header" id="header">
  <nav class="nav container">
    <a href="#" class="nav__logo">
      <img src="https://github.com/bedimcode/responsive-landing-page-headphones/blob/main/assets/img/logo.png?raw=true" alt="">
    </a>

    <div class="nav__menu" id="nav-menu">
      <ul class="nav__list">
        <li class="nav__item">
          <a href="#home" class="nav__link active-link">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav__item">
          <a href="#specs" class="nav__link">Specs</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav__item">
          <a href="#case" class="nav__link">Case</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <a href="" class="toggle-menu" role="button" aria-controls="menu-wrapper" aria-label="Open navigation" aria-expanded="false">
        <lottie-player src="https://assets8.lottiefiles.com/packages/lf20_nzuitqg1.json"></lottie-player>
      </a>
  </nav>
</header>

<main class="main">
  <!--=============== HOME ===============-->
  <section class="home section" id="home">
    <div class="home__container container grid">
      <div>
        <img src="https://github.com/bedimcode/responsive-landing-page-headphones/blob/main/assets/img/home.png?raw=true" alt="" class="home__img">
      </div>

      <div class="home__data">
        <div class="home__header">
          <h1 class="home__title">On ear</h1>
          <h2 class="home__subtitle">Beats 3</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="home__footer">
          <h3 class="home__title-description">Overview</h3>
          <p class="home__description">Enjoy award-winning Beats sound with wireless listening freedom and a sleek,
            streamlined design with comfortable padded earphones, delivering first-rate playback.
          </p>
          <a href="#" class="button button--flex">
            <span class="button--flex">
              <i class="ri-shopping-bag-line button__icon"></i></i> Add to Bag
            </span>
            <span class="home__price">$299</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!--=============== SPONSOR ===============-->
  <section class="sponsor section">
    <div class="sponsor__container container grid">
      <img src="https://github.com/bedimcode/responsive-landing-page-headphones/blob/main/assets/img/sponsor1.png?raw=true" alt="" class="sponsor__img">
      <img src="https://github.com/bedimcode/responsive-landing-page-headphones/blob/main/assets/img/sponsor2.png?raw=true" alt="" class="sponsor__img">
      <img src="https://github.com/bedimcode/responsive-landing-page-headphones/blob/main/assets/img/sponsor3.png?raw=true" alt="" class="sponsor__img">
      <img src="https://github.com/bedimcode/responsive-landing-page-headphones/blob/main/assets/img/sponsor4.png?raw=true" alt="" class="sponsor__img">
    </div>
  </section>

  <!--=============== SPECS ===============-->
  <section class="specs section grid" id="specs">
    <h2 class="section__title section__title-gradient">Specs</h2>

    <div class="specs__container container grid">
      <div class="specs__content grid">
        <div class="specs__data">
          <i class="ri-bluetooth-line specs__icon"></i>
          <h3 class="specs__title">Connection</h3>
          <span class="specs__subtitle">Bluetooth v5.2</span>
        </div>

        <div class="specs__data">
          <i class="ri-battery-charge-line specs__icon"></i>
          <h3 class="specs__title">Battery</h3>
          <span class="specs__subtitle">Duration 40h</span>
        </div>

        <div class="specs__data">
          <i class="ri-plug-line specs__icon"></i>
          <h3 class="specs__title">Load</h3>
          <span class="specs__subtitle">Fast charge 4.2-AAC</span>
        </div>

        <div class="specs__data">
          <i class="ri-mic-line specs__icon"></i>
          <h3 class="specs__title">Microphone</h3>
          <span class="specs__subtitle">Supports Apple Siri <br> and Google</span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div>
        <img src="https://github.com/bedimcode/responsive-landing-page-headphones/blob/main/assets/img/specs.png?raw=true" alt="" class="specs__img">
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!--=============== CASE ===============-->
  <section class="case section grid" id="case">
    <h2 class="section__title section__title-gradient">Case</h2>

    <div class="case__container container grid">
      <div>
        <img src="https://github.com/bedimcode/responsive-landing-page-headphones/blob/main/assets/img/case.png?raw=true" alt="" class="case__img">
      </div>

      <div class="case__data">
        <p class="case__description">With a comfortable and adaptable case so that you can
          store it whenever you want, and keep your durability forever.
        </p>
        <a href="#" class="button button--flex">
          <i class="ri-information-line button__icon"></i> More info
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!--=============== DISCOUNT ===============-->
  <section class="discount section">
    <div class="discount__container container grid">
      <div class="discount__animate">
        <h2 class="discount__title">Immerse yourself in <br> your music</h2>
        <p class="discount__description">Get it now, up to 50% off.</p>
        <a href="#" class="button button--flex">
          <i class="ri-shopping-bag-line button__icon"></i> Shop Now
        </a>
      </div>

      <img src="https://github.com/bedimcode/responsive-landing-page-headphones/blob/main/assets/img/discount.png?raw=true" alt="" class="discount__img">
    </div>
  </section>
</main>

   


<!--=============== SCROLL UP ===============-->
<a href="#" class="scrollup" id="scroll-up">
  <i class="ri-arrow-up-s-line scrollup__icon"></i>
</a>

<!--=============== SCROLL REVEAL ===============-->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/scrollreveal"></script>
  

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@lottiefiles/lottie-player@latest/dist/lottie-player.js"></script>
  


</body></html>
```

Comment: What did you try and what specifically goes wrong?

Comment: I would like two things to happen as follows:

When clicked on one of the links the menu disappears.
at the same time the lottie animation goes back to hamburger icon state when clicked on a link, (it staying in X state)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following worked:

1. **define a variable** with array of all 3 menu-link:

```js
// querySelectorAll gets you all 3 menu-links
const menuLink = document.querySelectorAll(".nav__link");
```

2. **define a function()** that closes the menu and plays backwards the lottie player:

```js
function closeMenu() {
  // pageHeader.classList.toggle(menuOpenedClass); // would also work;
  pageHeader.classList.remove("menu-open");

  // play lottie player segment backwards
  player.getLottie().playSegments([45, 0], true);
}
```

3. **Add event listener** to all 3 menu-links:

```js
menuLink.forEach(function (element) {
  element.addEventListener("click", function () {
    closeMenu();
  })
});
```

Comment: Thank you Jurgen, that is exactly what I asked for. Much appreciated also thanks for reminding me to accept this as solved otherwise I wouldn't know it.